# How I can get keycode and make multimedia keys usable?

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts

I've an Asus N73S which have non-functional multimedia keys.
I have "direct access" keys but also "indirect access" keys (via Fn + ...).
The "Windows" key doesn't work either.

These keys don't respond with xev or showkey and nothing appears in /var/log/messages

How to make the buttons usable ?

Another strange trick, only the two buttons for adjusting the brightness (Fn + F5 and Fn + F6) are functional. Where this thing is set?

I'm on Fedora 15 (Lovelock).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try commenting out all "InputDevice" sections in your xorg.conf file. This will make recent xorg servers to use the default "evdev" device, which usually picks up all event devices and makes the keys available for use.

Comment: Yeah, it worked commenting out the « InputClass » section automatically generated by system-setup-keyboard. Thanks !

Comment: @Loïc It's much easier than it used to be. :-)